# Refresh Token not Expiring AzureAD

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, refresh-token

The server should invalidate the refresh token that has already been used for generating
new access token and refresh tokens, however the refresh token can be used multiple times for
generating new tokens, without being invalidated, even though the server provides a new
refresh token each time the request is triggered. I'm using AzureAD for my application.

I know there is a way to expire refresh tokens that have already been used using Refresh Token Rotation Implementation but is it implementable in AzureAD.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that it is working as they have designed it.
The purpose is that you can take the new refresh token and replace the one you have in your cache.
If you are running a distributed application, it is a good thing that the current refresh token doesn't immediately stop working since it allows the other instances to keep working while the token is refreshed in another.
As far as I am aware, there is no place to change this behaviour.